# Prevent to load multi action with click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, load

I have a large application with Angular include modal form and wizard form and etc .
there is problem that i don't know how to deal with that in best way .
the problem is : when user click on modal button there is a delay to open modal meantime if user click on something else all of them run .
i mean modal and other action run together .
what's the best way to handle this ?

```
       i konw there is a way to add loading bar and add overlay shadow
 with z-index to prevent another click .
```

thx for your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have said, the easiest way is to use a blocking element preventing users from clicking multiple times. If you don't want to do that, an alternative is use angular events, eg. broadcast/emit/on, each element listens to some events and toggles click enabled status. Or you can use ng-disabled, and set a rootScope variable eg messageSending, whenever a model dialog is requested, set messageSending = true.

Comment: can you please create a very simple fiddle ? thanks in advance

Comment: I will update jsfiddle incrementally. First is your original version from my simplified model: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/12529/, where you can click button 'foo' and then button 'bar'. Note that there will be alerts shown for each click. Second is the one I mentioned above using ng-disabled: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/12532/, where clicking one button disables the other one.

Comment: sorry for being late and thx for your support,
fiddles not working,am i right ?

Comment: I just tried, ad they worked. So which functionality is missing/not working?

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: yes sure, fiddles that you created is not working and when i click on buttons nothing happend